# dynamic sum in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want last column 'Output' as stated in table. here the logic is :

```
for row 1 : sum of LBKUM & weekly_qty
for row 2 : sum of output of row 1 & weekly_qty of row 2
for row 3 : sum of output of row 2 & weekly_qty of row 3
for row 4 : sum of output of row 3 & weekly_qty of row 4
```

and so on.

Unlike other running total, I want LBKUM only once (in first row calculation) and in the next steps, output of previous row should be considered as shown in the description.

I hope this much would be sufficient.

Thanks in advance.

| LOGSYS | MATNR | PLANT | LBKUM | QTY_WITHDRAWL | PLUS_QTY | WEEK | WEEKLY_QTY | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 387 | 484 | 06 | 97 | 1505 |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 1238 | 2080 | 07 | 842 | 2347 |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 1826 | 1600 | 08 | -226 | 2121 |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 1786 | 1920 | 09 | 134 | 2255 |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 1445 | 1120 | 10 | -325 | 1930 |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 1224 | 800 | 11 | -424 | 1506 |
| SAP | 123456789 | 1234 | 1408 | 1299 | 1280 | 12 | -19 | 1487 |

Comment: `lag(0, 1, lbkum) over(partition by <whatever> order by week asc) + sum(weekly_qty) over(<the same>)`. The first function will return `LBKUM` for the first row and 0 for subsequent rows.

Comment: What does <the same> means here?

Comment: You have some window specification to calculate running sum. This window specification should be used in `lag` and `sum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```sql
SELECT week,
       FIRST_VALUE(lbkum) OVER (ORDER BY week)
       + SUM(weekly_qty) OVER (ORDER BY week) AS running_total
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (LOGSYS, MATNR, PLANT, LBKUM, QTY_WITHDRAWL, PLUS_QTY, WEEK, WEEKLY_QTY, Output) AS
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408,  387,  484, 06,   97, 1505 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408, 1238, 2080, 07,  842, 2347 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408, 1826, 1600, 08, -226, 2121 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408, 1786, 1920, 09,  134, 2255 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408, 1445, 1120, 10, -325, 1930 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408, 1224,  800, 11, -424, 1506 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAP', 123456789, 1234, 1408, 1299, 1280, 12,  -19, 1487 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| WEEK | RUNNING_TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1505 |
| 7 | 2347 |
| 8 | 2121 |
| 9 | 2255 |
| 10 | 1930 |
| 11 | 1506 |
| 12 | 1487 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uiHz4fdq)